# Least squares regression of NPS

Tags: regression, time-series, categorical-data, least-squares

I would like to monitor customer satisfaction over time and would ideally like to use NPS for that. Specifically, I would like to see if there's an overall trend over time. Could I regress Net Promoter Score (defined below) using dummy variables at 6 month time intervals?

If not could I use the raw average customer satisfaction score (i.e. the mean response to how likely they would be to recommend to a friend)?

- I will sample satisfaction every six months
- data is approximately normally distributed (central limit theorem) because the sample size will be ~1000 in each period.
- The survey is essentially repeated cross section with removal 
  the population size is 6million
  I would like to measure whether satisfaction is changing over time for the overall population and also look at the changes within four (roughly equal) subpopulations.

Net Promoter Score (NPS) is based on a direct question: How likely is it that you would recommend our company/product/service to a friend or colleague? The scoring for this answer is most often based on a 0 to 10 scale.[3]

Promoters are those who respond with a score of 9 or 10 and are considered loyal enthusiasts. Detractors are those who respond with a score of 0 to 6 - unhappy customers. Scores of 7 and 8 are passives, and they will only count towards the total number of respondents, but not directly affect the formula. NPS is calculated by subtracting the percentage of customers who are Detractors from the percentage of customers who are Promoters.[4]

Forecaster - thank you, it sounds like you may be right, so I would just plot the values on a chart to see it visually and maybe perform an F test to see if the differences are significant? Also the frequency chart is a really good idea, thank you very much

Comment: What is "NPS"? Please spell out your acronyms. Are you wondering if this has changed since the last measurement, or if there is an overall trend, or what exactly?

Comment: I just defined it in the question sorry - it's a management tool that's often used by companies to measure customer satisfaction. I would like to see if there's an overall trend over time. And thanks a lot!!

Comment: how often did you sample customer satisfaction?  Was each sample on an independent group?  What does your data look like?  For each survey, are the data normally distributed (with a mean, say, around what?), bimodal, skewed, outliers?  Spend time looking at and understanding your data before thinking about modeling it - it will help you develop a more precise question/hypothesis.  Is it your goal to see if people are changing categories, if certain categories are changing in their mean satisfaction, or do you want to look at overall trends in satisfaction regardless of group classification?

Comment: Why do you want to regress, a simple time series plot of scores can tell you if your trend is improving or not. Similarly  Frequency table over time if you are counting promoters, distractors or passives over time can help you in detecting trend.May be I'm missing something, dummies are useful to capture seasonality not trends.

Comment: It's a very relevant question. @forecaster but that's just eyeballing data. We want to have a model to make it possible to interpret more objectively.